# React Native Flat List: Space Flatlist children evenly to fit the current screen height

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to render **N** number of `Flatlist` components and have them fit the rest of the screen perfectly without there being a need to scroll. This is what my app currently looks like.
[image: I have my App Header on top Intelligent Assistant]

I have my `Flatlist` children which are my use cases rendered below my Intelligent Assistant Header. I need the `flatlist` components to fit the current user screen perfectly for N number of use cases. In this case, there is a lot of empty space left which I want the **N** number of children to fit in evenly.

Here is my `App.js` file

```
 return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Header appName='Intelligent Assistant'/>
      <View > 
        <FlatList 
          data = {useCases} 
          renderItem = {({item}) => <Usecase useCase = {item} />}
          />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex : 1 ,
    paddingTop : 60,
  },
});
```

Here is my Usecase.js file

```
const Usecase = ({useCase}) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.useCase}>
            <View style = {styles.useCaseView}>
                <Text style = {styles.useCaseText}>{useCase.description}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    useCase : {
        padding : 15,
        backgroundColor : '#f8f8f8',
        borderBottomWidth : 1,
        borderColor : '#eee',
    },
    useCaseView : {
        flexDirection : 'column',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'space-evenly',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {Dimensions} from ‘react-native’;
const deviceheight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const Usecase = ({useCase}) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style = {[styles.useCase,{height: (deviceheight - YOUR_HEADER_BAR_HEIGHT)/useCases.length}]}>
            <View style = {styles.useCaseView}>
                <Text style = {styles.useCaseText}>{useCase.description}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Since you're using `{borderBottomWidth : 1}`, You'll have to substract number of rows in that height calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's solved :)